# Installing Lion on my mac

Tags: macos, mac, operating-systems, osx-lion

This is a very basic question.I have a .dmg file of Lion on one of my partitions.How can I install Lion on my mac using that?What should be the startup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the .dmg which will mount the disk image.
Follow the on-screen instructions, should be pretty straight forward, I believe it says "Install OS X" or "Install OS X Lion"

Answer (score 1):

To make it a clean install:

Burn your .dmg file on a CD or put it on a USB stick/external hard drive. There are heaps of tutorials how to do this, like [here](http://lifehacker.com/5823096/how-to-burn-your-own-lion-install-dvd-or-flash-drive)